# C# - show culture on numbers

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I want to show culture on integers, but `"n"` number format gives me double format output.

Here is a small example

```
int i = 10000;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("n", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

This gives me out put as `10,000.00`

I want output as `10,000`

Workaround like modifying string is not what I need.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `n0` instead of `n` in the format.

```
int i = 10000;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

Output would be:

```
10,000
```

Or you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("N0"));
```

You may see: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

**The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier.**

> The numeric ("N") format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where "-" indicates a negative number
>   symbol if required, "d" **indicates a digit (0-9)**,

*By the way "N" or "n" are same*

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:n0}",i, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

or closer to your original

```
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("n0"), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/MDJI27648

Answer (score 0):

What kind of number do you want to see? It is a monetary amount or what?:

c   (currency)  string.Format("{0:c}",i)    $1,000,000.00

d   (decimal)   string.Format("{0:d}",i)    1000000

e   (scientific)    string.Format("{0:e}",i)    1.000000e+006

f   (fixed point)   string.Format("{0:f}",i)    1000000.00

g   (general)   string.Format("{0:g}",i)    1000000

n   (with separator)string.Format("{0:n}",i)    1,000,000.00

x   Hexadezimal string.Format("{0:x4}",i)   f4240

Answer (score 0):

The number of post-decimal point digits printed by `"n"` is given by the [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits.aspx) property.

You can change this, and then use the `CultureInfo` in all your `ToString` calls to make sure your strings are consistent:

```
var customCI = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
customCI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;

Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("n", customCI));
```